# How to fix EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to update a record using `EF` but getting following exception:

> Inner Exception 1:
>   SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UpdatedDate', table 'PAS_DEV.dbo.RepairOrder'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

`UpdatedDate` ia `notNull` in database table. I am passing `dateTime.now` value so I am not sure why EF thinks that it is null.

**Code:**

```
public class RepairOrder:PasBase
{
    [Key]
    public long RepairOrderId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; 
}

if (_context.RepairOrder.Any(o => o.RepairOrderId == poViewModel.RepairOrderId))
{
    var actionobject = _context.RepairOrder.Where(a => a.RepairOrderId == poViewModel.RepairOrderId).SingleOrDefault();
    actionobject.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _context.RepairOrder.Update(actionobject);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(actionobject);
}
```

**Table Structure:**

[image]

Comment: Try to set you logging to debug then you will see the queries that are generated. Maybe this gives you some insides on whats happening behind the scenes

Comment: Do you really need this line `_context.RepairOrder.Update(actionobject);` ? The `actionobject` is already part of the context so you may be able to simply call `SaveChanges`. Try commenting it out.

Comment: @jcruz This is very strange. Your suggestion works but the confusion is, I have two values `createdDate` and `updateDate` where only `createdDate` is updating. I am not sure what is going on with `updateDate`. Datataype is same, still??

Comment: @jcruz Found the issue. Here I was inheriting another class which has nullable `updatedDate`. This was the issue. I didn't need that so removed and worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if (actionobject != null)
{
    actionobject.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _context.Entry(actionobject).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Don't need this since `actionobject` is already attached to the context.

Comment: @CSharper You should probably do a null check for actionobject before updating and saving.

Comment: @PateeGutee Here `actionObjrct` is not null. All needed values are available.

Comment: Probably just a typo but your UpdatedDate property has no closing curly brace:

Comment: @PateeGutee It is a typo.